# Tool for displaying timeline view of kernel/userspace execution trace

Tags: linux, kernel, tracing, ftrace

I've used the ftrace tool **trace-cmd** for recording scheduling tracepoints and syscall tracepoints. I can inspect them visually using the [kernelshark](http://rostedt.homelinux.com/kernelshark/) GUI program. It dislays per-core timelines and per-task timelines as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

I can see when interrupts are triggered, when the scheduler is invoked and when system calls are being made and when they return. But when a system call is being made, kernelshark makes no distinction between the task running in userspace and it running in kernelspace.

I want a tool that allows me to see for a specific core when it is executing an interrupt handler; the currently traced process in userspace; or some task in userspace. Something similar to this picture:

[image]

Does anyone know of a tool for transforming ftrace data into that sort of format, be it as an svg file, a chrome trace-file or using any other format or tool?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Micrified No and I moved on to other things. But now https://www.eclipse.org/tracecompass/ exists which might be able to give the information I wanted back then. I wish something similar to the Windows program UIforETW was available for Linux. Maybe one day...

Comment: Ah shame. Well, thank you for the link to the eclipse project. I will check it out. Best of luck with your current endeavors!